# Pytorch Partial derivatives like tf.gradients with stop_gradients parameter

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation, derivative, autograd

Is there a way to calculate partial derivatives instead of total derivative with Pytorch like tf.gradients with parameter stop_gradients https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients

Example:

```
a = torch.tensor(1., requires_grad=True)
b = 2 * a
c = a + b
print(torch.autograd.grad(c, a, retain_graph=True))
```

Output `(tensor(3.),)`, Expected output: 1 for partial derivative.

I know we can use `b = 2*(a.detach())`. But what if `d=2*c`. In that case, I want to keep calculating the total derivative `dd/da`. I want to get `dd/da=6` just like there is no `a.detach` instead of 2.

Background: I am trying to calculate the last hidden layer partial gradient w.r.t the the first hidden in RNN. Then I still need to calculate `loss.backward()` where I don't want to detach the hidden layer.

Thank you all.